# Eclipse / SonarQube Integration: How to handle Checkstyle / PMD / FindBugs

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd, sonarlint

If I work with Eclipse and want to use SonarQube as single source of code rules, I understand I need to use the SonarLint plugin. However, SonarLint will only check squid rules, no Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs rules (although they can be used in SonarQube).

My question: If a project has been using a Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs rule set, how should these rules be handled so that they can also be seen by the Eclipse developers?

Please consider these points:

- I don't want to manually export rules from SonarQube and install Eclipse plugins for Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs and configure them with the exported rules. That's too cumbersome.
- I see that some Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs are marked as deprecated and there are squid-replacements. Thats ok. But what do I do with all the rules that are not deprecated?

Comment: The question is, what is your setup? eg. we have a gradle script which installs all the checkstyle/firebug configurations, and a commit hook for git which checks that. Additionally to that, depending on your workflow aka if you use Pull Requests, there are plugins to show those issues within pullrequests. - as far as i know, that are the only options you have.

Comment: You either install the individual plugins, or you use SonarLint. No third option afaik. SonarLint uses whatever is configured in the quality profile on the server. If your SonarQube quality profile includes Checkstyle, FindBugs etc. then SonarLint will check them, too.

Comment: @Thomas Jensen: SonarLint will *not* check Checkstyle/Findbugs/PMD rules, even though they are successfully checked in SonarQube (cf. http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/ , FAQ question no. 4). Statement from SonarLint: "SonarLint supports the SonarSource Analyzers (SonarJava, SonarJS, ...) and also custom rules extending these SonarSource analyzers. We don't plan to support plugins running third-party analyzers (like PMD, Android Lint, JSLint...). Most of the time those analyzers already have dedicated IDE integration."

Comment: Dang, this is so annoying, they keep dropping features in every single release. Sorry I had missed that this feature is gone, too. So, your only option is to install the individual plugins, sad as it sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how we solved this issue (90% solution):

1. Replaced all deprecated Checkstyle/PMD/FindBugs rules with recommended squid rules. -> This left over 80 Checkstyle, 16 PMD and 0 FindBugs rules (and 60 squid rule), eliminating FindBugs.
2. Use SonarLint + Checkstyle plugins in Eclipse. For Checkstyle, we export the rules XML from SonarQube, put them in our version control and configure Checkstyle plugin to use that.
3. Ignore PMD in Eclipse and use direct browser access to SonarQube to see PMD rule violations in code reviews. This saves us from installing/confguring PMD for "only 16 rules".

The solution makes about 90% of our rules visible in Eclipse. The price we pay:

- Install & configure 2 plugins for rules checking instead of 1.
- Manually keep Checkstyle rules XML up to date whenever SonarQube updates lead to changes.
- squid rule violations only visible for opened classes, and in a separate "SonarLint On-the-fly" view.
- Only 90% of rules visible directly in Eclipse.

We would be very happy if one day SonarLint would display *all* SonarQube rules violations in Eclipse's standard "Problems" view, covering workspace and selection scopes. Then we would only need a single Eclipse plugin and SonarQube would be the only rules repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion to the SonarLint developers to provide a solution: SonarLint should be able to retrieve all violations from SonarQube and display them in the standard "Problems" view in Eclipse. Like this, SonarLint does not need to execute Checkstyle/Findbugs/PMD rules locally, so there will be no compatibility/support issues. At the same time, the Eclipse developer sees *all* violations without leaving Eclipse.

Comment: This was actually possible in earlier versions, too. %-/ It has the drawback of being frequently out of date, though. Developers normally want immediate feedback on the code they are writing.

Comment: I understand. However, having a possibly outdated information is IMHO better that having none. For the developer it It would be important to see the time a specific rule violation was found. And there should be an option to trigger SonarLint to refresh itself from SonarQube.